# Code base64 encoded performance

Tags: php, performance

I want to encode my code with base64 to limit (NOT prevent) licence violations.

```
$_Z=__FILE__;$_N=$string;$_D=base64_encode;eval($_K($_N));
```

I want to encode it recursively 6 times. I am wondering if this could make any huge performance impact. When I tested it with simple 100 lines code it made 0,5Mb difference in memory usage. But when I tested entire extension inside Magento code (cache disabled) it was just 0,2MB difference comparing with decoded version. The extension has 20 different php files.

What I am worried is what will happen on live on different production systems. Do you think I should encode it just let's say 3 times to avoid performance impact?

Comment: I think that just N times base64 encode is useless.

Comment: This was just example, I implemented also some other things. I am not worried about how useful is base64 but about performance impact.

Comment: You should consider ionCube encoder or ZendGuard instead of pointless approaches with base64

Comment: Please stay on topic. My question is NOT how to protect the code or which way is effective to protect my code. These topics have been already answered many times in other questions here on stackoverflow. My question is ONLY about performance, what performance impact will make base64 n times as described above in my question.

Comment: @JohnClark, php interpreter cannot use bytecode cache. This question cannot be answered its highly dependencies on your application, hardware and environment. Just test it with `ab` or something else.